# Using libGDX for business app

Tags: libgdx, cross-platform

I am just looked at [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibGDX) says

> It is cross-platform, supporting Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Android, iOS, and web browsers with WebGL support.

Can I use it for non-game development, e.g. business app (that usually are database centric)

Are there widgets library and advanced widget like table?

Maybe there is some real cross-platform alternative (PC+mobile+web)...

Comment: There is a widget library with tables built in (Google Libgdx scene2d.ui). But it is not as powerful as Android's UI or Cocoa. There is no wysiwyg editor or Xml parser. You have to construct it in Java. And Libgdx doesn't have SQLite built in. You would have to build some kind of database interface for each platform you target.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tenfour04

[Scene2d.ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) is starting point, there is dedicated page for [Table](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table)

[image]

and generally read more at wiki